# Validate a string by checking its pattern

Tags: java

I would like to know if there is a way to check if a string is valid. I need to allow users to enter multiple "-m(number)" as follows:

```
-m 5 -m444 -m 33
```

Note that spaces doesn't matter as long as the pattern is -m(number) continuously.

I am currently using for loop to check character by character but find it tedious. Is there a way to simply do it using pattern matching without manually checking character by character?

Edit:     `-m 5 -m444 -m 33 344`

Should be invalid as the 344 behind should be `-m 344` or `-m344`

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches-java.lang.String-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thing `-m\s*[0-9]+` might do what you want.

Note that in java REGEX, you'll need to escape the \ : `-m\\s*(?<number>[0-9]+)`

EDIT : I added a capturing group, so you can use it like that :

```
private static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("-m\\s*(?<number>[0-9]+)");

public static void main(String[] args)  {

    String test = "-m 5 -m444 -m 33 ";
    Matcher matcher = PATTERN.matcher(test);
    while(matcher.find()){
        System.out.println(matcher.group("number"));
    }

}
```

That returns :

`5
444
33`

EDIT : if you do not care about parsing, you can just go with the following :

```
private static final Pattern PATTERN_VALIDATION = Pattern.compile("(\\s*-m\\s*[0-9]+\\s*)+");

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String test = "-m 5 -m444 -m 33 ";
    Matcher matcher = PATTERN_VALIDATION.matcher(test);
    System.out.println(matcher.matches());

}
```

Will print `true`.

While checking for `-m 5 -m444 -m 33 344` will print false.

Comment: Awesome, but apologies I missed out something in my question. What if user keys `-m 5 -m444 -m 33 344`? In this case the `344` behind is invalid because it should be `-m 344` or `-m344`

Comment: You can freely test my second code block and see for yourself that `-m 5 -m444 -m 33 344` will print `false`. If you use my first pattern, you will only catch 5, 444 and 33 (but no error will be thrown).

Answer (score 2):

A good way to do this would be to use Java regex. you can use the following sample to validate the code:

```
String str = "-m 5 -m444 -m 33";
str.matches("(-m\\s?\\d+)(\\s+(-m\\s?\\d+))*") //returns true
```

To get a breakdown of the regex see the following link: [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/7azHmj/2)

Basically the first part, `(-m\s?\d+)`, matches one "-m", zero or one whitespace chars, and then one or more decimal chars. Rest matches the same pattern, zero to many times, with whitespace in between.

There are also fancier ways to do the same regex, but my regex-fu is not quite at that level. Maybe someone else can contribute a more DRY solution, but I think for a simple case like this it is more than sufficient :)

Answer (score 1):

You can go with

```
String.matches(String regex)
```

[Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29)